# Clarification in regards to using safe_time in YugabyteDB

Tags: distributed-transactions, yugabytedb

The document https://docs.yugabyte.com/latest/architecture/transactions/transactional-io-path/  says that a distributed txn can choose the `safe_time` from one of the involved tablets, and that `safe_time` considers the first uncommitted raft log’s hybrid timestamp. Does this mean that  yugabytedb guarantees that all txn can read the data written by the txn committed before it starts?

[Disclaimer]: This question was first asked on the YugabyteDB Community Slack channel.

Answer (score 2):

There are two components to choosing a read timestamp for a snapshot isolation transaction: (1) it needs to be recent enough to capture everything that has been committed before the transaction started; and (2) it needs to be as low as possible to avoid unnecessary wait. Choosing the safe time from the first tablet that a transaction reads from or writes to is just a heuristic towards the above goal.  Safe time considers the timestamp of the first uncommitted (in the Raft sense) record in that tablet's Raft log as one of the inputs, and what actually goes into safe time calculation is that uncommitted timestamp minus "epsilon" (smallest possible hybrid time step) so that that record committing will not change the view of data as of this timestamp (and also safe time is capped by the hybrid time leader lease of the tablet's leader so that we are safe against leader changes and a new leader trying to read at a new timestamp past the leader lease expiration). So, all of the above concerns the "snapshot safety" (i.e. the property that if we are reading at some time read_ht, we are guaranteed that no writes will be done to that data with timestamps <= read_ht). If safe time on a tablet has not reached a particular read_ht when a read request arrives at that tablet, the tablet will wait for it to reach read_ht before starting the read operation. Now, let's address the question how we guarantee that all the data written prior to a transaction starting is visible to that transaction. This is done through a mechanism called "read restarts" and a clock skew assumption. If a read request on behalf of a snapshot isolation transaction with a read time read_ht encounters a committed record with a commit timestamp range between read_ht and read_ht + max_clock_skew, that record might have been committed prior to the transaction starting (due to clock skew) and we have to restart the read request at the timestamp of that transaction. The way this is implemented has some optimizations: the value read_ht + max_clock_skew is only computed once per transaction and does not change with read restarts, and we call it global_limit. It is an upper bound on the commit timestamp of any transaction that could have committed prior to our transaction operation starting, and by setting read_ht = global_limit (which is actually suitable in some cases, like long-running reporting queries), we can safely avoid any read restarts. There is also another similar mechanism called local_limit, which limits the number of restarts to one per tablet. So, with read restarts, we can be sure that a read request will capture all records that were written prior to the transaction starting, even with clock skew.